# Is there a way to force mount a device in a different format?

Tags: mount, sd-card

sorry for the weird title, but I'm just wondering if there is a way for `mount` to ignore a device's filesystem format and instead, mount a device in a different format?

basically, I'm asking if something like mounting a fat16 device as a fat device would be possible.

I'm asking because one of my devices somehow corrupted my sd card and I'm seeing if this would be the right way to recover it.

Comment: that is an XY question ... asking a question about a perceived solution to a problem that you are trying to solve, instead of asking about the problem

Comment: `mount -t filesystem -o ro /dev/what /mnt/where` If it's really corrupted the kernel drivers are normally quite bad at recovering data. R-Studio Undelete is a much better application: https://www.r-studio.com/?GIMCX000

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description of the problem, wouldn't try to solve it by mounting a fa32 filesystem using a different format.
Instead you might want to use a tool like [Photorec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) and [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)

This tool will attempt to recover data, no matter what the original format was.

Comment: Another thing to consider is that 
There are compatibility issues between Fat and exFat (exFat is under some licensing issues, so a lot of linux devices don't like it), and windows likes to format USB device or SD card larger than 32GB (don't quote me on the exact number) using exFat which then a lot of cameras or devices running Linux within them, won't like to mount and edit, also a lot of older cameras have issues with sd cards larger than 16GB or so...